# How to add transition effect in Current running scene in cocos2d iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

How to add transition effect in Current running scene in cocos2d iphone. Means I am making a game and after each goal I want to give a fade effect or any type of effect on the current running scene.

If I write this, It replace current scene to its new scene. But I don't want to replace scene.

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:1.0f scene:[GamePage scene]]];
```

Is there some way to show effect on the current page like this. I know that it is wrong but I want something like this :

`[self transitionEffect:[CCTransitionFade actionWithDuration:0.5]];`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Scene,Layer (Subclass of CCNode) action related to Opacity will not work. !

You can Either Use transition, or Must have to apply CCFadeTo to all of your sprite.

But If you are choosing to CCFadeTo to all sprites, this will require allocation of lots of actions suddenly ! FPS slow down !!

Another best approach:

Tell to your designer, to make 1 x 1 pixel Square black dot image.
Add this code at last in the init method.

```
   CCSprite *temp=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"squaredotBlack.png"];
   temp.position=ccp(s.w/2,s.h/2);
   [self addChild:temp z:50000];    //set as most top layer
   temp.scaleX=s.w;
   temp.scaleY=s.h;
    temp.opacity=0;
```

Then Apply, For "Fade out" process of whole screen, Increase the opacity.

```
  temp.opacity=0; 
  [temp runAction:[CCFadeTo actionWithDuration:1 opacity:255]];   //0 to 255
```

Then Apply, For "Fade In" process of whole screen, decrease the opacity.

```
   temp.opacity=255; // this will cover whole screen with black color
              [temp runAction:[CCFadeTo actionWithDuration:1 opacity:0]]; //255 to 0
```

Comment: It would be easier to just top a CCColorLayer with color black and opacity 0 onto the scene, and then run a CCFadeTo action to the desired opacity on that layer...no need for dummy png then.

Answer (score 1):

you can run an action on the entire CCLayer

```
[self runAction:[CCFadeOut actionWithDuration:0.5f]];
```

or you can use CCFadeTo to fade to a desired opacity.

Comment: This code works, but it only work to CCLayer. I added some sprites over the layer and I want effect on the whole scene not to only Layer. Please give me the code for Entire Scene.

Comment: Just send the runAction method to your scene instance instead of a layer.